# index of bounds e problemas com timer

Tags: delphi, timer

Seguinte, eu tenho um timer que preenche 2 campos em um webbrowser, o mesmo faz a seguinte função...

```
var 
  pega : string; 
begin 
  pega := Listaimportados.Items[i]; 
  I := i +1 
  nome.text := Copy(pega, 0, 10); 
  Webbrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.Item('login', 0).value := nome.text;
```

nisso ele vai repetindo a ação a cada 4 segundos, como vocês podem ver o i+1 pula para a próxima linha, que no caso está importada em listaimportados(listbox).

porém eu tenho um problema, se eu inserir menos de um item no listbox(listaimportados) ele começa a dar erro, list of bounds, como resolver?

Comment: O Que deveria fazer quando chegasse a última linha?

Comment: Parar o timer, no caso timer1.enabled := false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você disse nos comentários que quando chegasse ao fim, você deveria parar o timer. 
Nesse caso é simples:

```
var 
  pega : string; 
begin 
  if I = Listaimportados.Count then
  begin
    timer1.Enabled:= False;
    Exit;
  end;
  pega := Listaimportados.Items[i]; 
  I := i +1 
  nome.text := Copy(pega, 0, 10); 
  Webbrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.Item('login', 0).value := nome.text;
```

Nesse código, estou assumindo que Listaimportados é uma instancia de uma classe `TStringList`